# Listing columns on a Slick table

Tags: scala, slick

I have a Slick 3.0 table definition similar to the following:

```
case class Simple(a: String, b: Int, c: Option[String])

trait Tables { this: JdbcDriver =>
  import api._

  class Simples(tag: Tag) extends Table[Simple](tag, "simples") {
    def a = column[String]("a")
    def b = column[Int]("b")
    def c = column[Option[String]]("c")

    def * = (a, b, c) <> (Simple.tupled, Simple.unapply)
  }

  lazy val simples = TableQuery[Simples]

} 

object DB extends Tables with MyJdbcDriver
```

I would like to be able to do 2 things:

1. Get a list of the column names as `Seq[String]`
2. For an instance of `Simple`, generate a  `Seq[String]` that would correspond to how the data would be inserted into the database using a raw query (e.g. `Simple("hello", 1, None)` becomes `Seq("'hello'", "1", "NULL")`)

What would be the best way to do this using the Slick table definition?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- First of all it is not possible to trick Slick and change the order on the left side of the `<>` operator in the `*` method without changing the order of values in `Simple`, the row type of `Simples`, i.e. what Ben assumed is not possible. The `ProvenShape` return type of   the `*` projection method ensures that there is a `Shape` available for translating between the `Column`-based type in * and the client-side type and if you write `def * = (c, b, a) <> Simple.tupled, Simple.unapply)` having Simple defined as `case class Simple(a: String, b: Int, c: Option[String])`, Slick will complain with an error "No matching Shape found. Slick does not know how to map the given types...". Ergo, you can iterate over all the elements of an instance of Simple with its **`productIterator`**.
- Secondly, you already have the definition of the `Simples` table in your code and querying metatables to get the same information you already have is not sensible. You can get all you column names with a one-liner **`simples.baseTableRow.create_*.map(_.name)`**. Note that the `*` projection of the table also defines the columns generated when you create the table schema. So the columns not mentioned in the projection are not created and the statement above is guaranteed to return exactly what you need and not to drop anything.

To recap briefly:

1. To get a list of the column names of the Simples table as `Seq[String]` use
   `simples.baseTableRow.create_*.map(_.name).toSeq`
2. To generate a `Seq[String]` that would correspond to how the data
   would be inserted into the database using a raw query for `aSimple`,
   an instance of `Simple` use `aSimple.productIterator.toSeq`

Comment: Thanks for the insight into `simples.baseTableRow.create_*.map(_.name).toSeq`. It's good to know that it returns in the order of the projection. I think this completely answers the question (and I've chosen it as the answer). However, I don't think `productIterator` works if I defined the `<>` mapping using custom functions. Ideally, I would want to be able to the mapping directly to convert `aSimple` into a `Seq[String]`

Answer (score 1):

To get the column names, try this:

```
db.run(for {
       metaTables <- slick.jdbc.meta.MTable.getTables("simples")
       columns <- metaTables.head.getColumns
       } yield columns.map {_.name}) foreach println
```

This will print

```
Vector(a, b, c)
```

And for the case class values, you can use productIterator:

```
Simple("hello", 1, None).productIterator.toVector
```

is

```
Vector(hello, 1, None)
```

You still have to do the value mapping, and guarantee that the order of the columns in the table and the values in the case class are the same.

Comment: I like using the meta tables (I didn't know that was in Slick). Ideally, I'd want to use the Slick table mapping to keep the order the same. Do you know of any way to do that?

Comment: The order is the order of definition,  isn't it?

Comment: @Edmondo1984 The order for `productIterator` is the definition order, but I think what he means is that there is no guarantee that that will be the same as the column order on the table (e.g. if the last line of the class definition of `Simples` were `def * = (c, b, a) <> (Simple.tupled, Simple.unapply)`) in which case you couldn't use trivially match the column names from `getColumns` with the values of `productIterator`.